# OnElementPropertyChanged called infinely in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker

I have a custom Time picker renderer in my xamarin forms application

In my renderer i have

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, 

    PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
                try
                {

                    if (e.PropertyName == iOSCustomTimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)
                    {
                        var temp = sender as iOSCustomTimePicker;   
                        picker.Hour = temp.Time.Hours;
                        picker.Minute = temp.Time.Minutes;
                        //TimeSpan value = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
                        //this.Element.SetValue(iOSCustomTimePicker.TimeProperty, value);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                }
            }
```

And i use it in xaml

```
<control:iOSCustomTimePicker x:Name="cli_staffrequest_addShiftTime_timePicker1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Time="{Binding ShiftEndTimeSelected}" 
          HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" StyleId="uit_staffHiring_addShifts__timePicker1"/>
```

So when the ShiftEndTimeSelected in ViewModel changes i get a hit in OnElementPropertyChanged and i change the time

Now my issue is sometimes i get infinite hits in OnElementPropertyChanged 
and thus calling the Garbage Collector infinitely. How to figure out whats wrong. I am completely new to xamarin Forms

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry for the poor english

I think those lines are raising the event again:

```
base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
```

and

```
picker.Hour = temp.Time.Hours;
picker.Minute = temp.Time.Minutes;
```

Maybe this will not happens if you make this way on your event handler (you need to test):

```
try
{
    if (e.PropertyName == iOSCustomTimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        var temp = sender as iOSCustomTimePicker;   
        picker.Hour = temp.Time.Hours;
        picker.Minute = temp.Time.Minutes;
    }
    else
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{

}
```